# trying to Change to wp_register_sidebar_widget

Tags: widgets, user-registration

I got this in my theme:

```
register_sidebar_widget(array('Sidebar Login', 'widgets'), 'widget_sidebarLogin');
```

i want to change this to the updated Command aka

```
wp_register_sidebar_widget
```

But i seem to miss something cuz the widget doesent load after the change..

I tried this:

```
wp_register_sidebar_widget(
'SidebarLoginId',        // your unique widget id
'Sidebar Login',          // widget name
'widget_sidebarLogin',  // callback function
array(                  // options
    'description' => 'Some description'
)
```

What am i missing? 
is that "widgets" in the original 'register_sidebar_widget' 
array has a meaning othere then description ?

Comment: You're Missing This Function "widget_sidebarLogin"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function widget_sidebarLogin() {
    echo "Content of Your Widget";
}

wp_register_sidebar_widget(
    'sidebarLoginId',        // your unique widget id
    'SidebarLogin',          // widget name
    'widget_sidebarLogin',  // callback function
    array(                  // options
        'description' => 'Some Descriptions'
    )
);
```

Comment: 10x man but ofcourse i got the functions... just didnt think i need to paste it here..  its rather long.. Thanks anyhow.. its wirking now so i guess i had a typo or some unexplained something (like its somethimes happens)..